# If takes more than a minute to query in Larave controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

If it takes more than a minute to query to database inside laravel controller, how can you make vue wait until the data is ready to fetch or render?

> my axios code is:

```
axios
 .get('/api/data_/nodes')
 .then(response => {
  const data = response.data.data;
  })
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error);
  });
```

> Still got this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

*I use v-if however it still not working, since it takes more than 1 minute to query*

```
computed: {
 isDataLoaded() {
   const nestedLoaded = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => this.data[key].length !== 0);
   return this.data&& nestedLoaded.length !== 0;
 },
},
```

*It work before but since it takes more than a minute to query it does not work anymore, please helpe me :(*

> vue component:

```
<line-chart v-if="isDataLoaded"/>
```

Comment: try this `data: () => ({ isDataLoaded: false })` then inside axios success callback `then(res => this.isDataLoaded = true)`

Comment: yes, it works. However when it takes much longer still it gives the same error. Like if I query 5 rows it response, but if I query more than 5 rows it gives error.

Comment: If problem is with more than 5 rows then there is serious issue with server side (either PHP, MySQL or HW infrastructure).

Comment: @Aslam your comment was correct and working, it was my query algorithm that was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Tpojka yes the problem is with my query algorithm server side. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: Update your question with appropriate code from controller/model and someone could be more able to help.

Comment: @Tpojka I already solve it, I got it wrong with eloquent. I already use stored procedure. Thanks for the help. My first problem was solve with Aslam help. So I don't think it is necessary to update the question.

Comment: Then feel free to describe solution in an answer so it could be helpful to others. Happy coding.